# bootstrap span and input full width in the same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I put in the same line a span and an input with a full width for both elements?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <span>Description</span>
    <input id="txtDesc" type="text"/>
 </div>
</div>

#txtDesc {
  width: 100%;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e4qvb7ck/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `white-space:nowrap` to the container of both elements:

CSS:

```
.col-xs-12 {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/1179/