# How to prevent bootstrap from collapsing input and img link at same line, whilst spanning 100%

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

### Basic concept

Create a selectbox + img link **inline** that span either max width (as set by CSS) or max window width. but stay inline whatever the horizontal size of the screen.

### Using:

- VS2015
- MVC 4
- Bootstrap 3.3.7
- Standard Site.CSS
  (sets max width of input/select/textbox to 400px)

With basic HTML code like so:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="cmbDivisionGroup" class="control-label">Division Group</label>
    <div class="form-inline">
            <select id="cmbDivisionGroup" class="form-control" name="DivisionGroup" style="width:95%;" >
                <option value="">Choose a Division group...</option>
                <option value="Some division">Some Division</option>
                <option value="Some other division">Some other division</option>
            </select>
            <span>
                <a href="/Division/addDivisionGroup" style="display: inline-block;" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Set to 'Not Interested' !">
                    <img alt="GoTo" src="/Resources/Adds Add file.png" height="30" border="0" width="30">
                </a>

            </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Something like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/7f891kj0/1/

### What I've tried...

Initially, the above code looks like:

[image]

Which is what we want...

But, after Bootstrap reaches its magical 768px, it collapses into:

[image]

Which is **NOT** what we want...

I've tried just about every possible combination of `<span>` `<container>` a variety of `<col-md-?>` embedded `<form-inline>` and `<row>` yet none of them seem to make it work as intended...?

I've tried using `style="width:95%"` and then attaching the img link which works, 'sort of' as it still collapses into two lines.
I've tried the bootstrap input-addon class but that is not how I would like the UI to look.

There is a other StackOverflow link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39009158/how-do-i-keep-a-span-on-the-same-line-as-an-input-using-bootstrap-3) though that doesn't have an answer to the question.
And another [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36150840/bootstrap-span-and-input-full-width-in-the-same-line) that I do not seem to be able to get working in my example. 
(Tested: https://jsfiddle.net/k9hbzvq5/)

I would appreciate anybody that has a good suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think changing the structure a lil you can achieve it this way

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="input-group">
      <select id="cmbDivisionGroup" class="form-control" name="DivisionGroup">
                <option value="">Choose a Division group...</option>
                <option value="Some division">Some Division</option>
                <option value="Some other division">Some other division</option>
            </select>
      <span class="input-group-btn">
         <a href="/Division/addDivisionGroup" style="display: inline-block;" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Set to 'Not Interested' !">
                    <img alt="GoTo" src="/Resources/Adds Add file.png" height="30" border="0" width="30">
                </a>
      </span>
    </div>
    <!-- /input-group -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div>
```